# Use getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() to get path before using it in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, path, flutter-futurebuilder

In this Flutter app, I want to build a list of items with thumbnails that are stored as file names in the database. The files are stored inside the application's directory and only the name is saved in the database.

When I build the list, I want to get the application's directory then join it with the file name. But I don't know how to do it because `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` is asynchronous and it doesn't return the value when I need it (before using `ListView.builder`)

My code, to make it clearer

```
class _ItemsWidgetState extends State<ItemsWidget> {
  String? appDir;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // this seems like the only place where I can get it
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((value) => appDir = value.path);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: widget.items,
        initialData: const [],
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                    final Item item = snapshot.data![index];
                    // $aappDir is NULL here
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: Image.file(File('$appDir/${item.thumbnailName}')),
                      title: Text(item.name,),
                    );
                  })
              : Center(child: Text('No items added'),),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

As you can see, `appDir` is null and `initState()` does not change that, even though it does get the directory. I need to understand better how this works and how can I make this work

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // <-- This can save your life
  final Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  print (documentDirectory);

  runApp(_App());
}
```

Comment: This might work. And then I pass it to widgets as a parameter? I have to pass it between 3 or 4 of them. I already have `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

Comment: `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` (usually the first call in main) can be used once at the entire app life cycle. This is useful to get ServiceBinding initialized for screen sizes, paths etc. You can make a static/global/constant varible to set by `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` before starting app then use it everywhere. `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` return the same Directory everywhere/everytime you call it:

Answer (score 0):

getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((value) => setState(() => appDir = value.path));